# How to test an ionic app 1 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I have been struggling for like two days and there is not a single clear tutorial available explaining the use of android studio in testing an ionic app. I have made the full fledged app in ionic 1 and i also configured android studio. Now what next ?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to open an ionic app inside android studio, you simply need to open the folder android with android studio. This folder is inside the platform folder created by ionic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Chrome Dev-Tools.
You will find some information here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have a ionic app and you added the android platform into it if not please add the platform using `ionic platform add android` command and after that it will create an android directory inside `platform` directory of you ionic project you have to just open that `android` directory on your `android studio` that it